# Is there an application for smartphone to upstream to YouTube and Facebook simultaneously for free?

Tags: gratis, mobile, streaming, youtube, facebook

I'm looking for an application for smartphone to upstream to YouTube and Facebook simultaneously for free ?

So far I've found and tried this one : https://streamlabs.com/mobile-app but it seems multistreaming requires a streamlabs Prime subscription : https://streamlabs.com/multistream

Do you know of any application that can "multistream" simultaneously for free ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this question is still relevant. The [Streamster app](https://streamster.io/products/mobile-streaming-app/) allows streaming to 2 targets (e.g. YouTube and Facebook) for free

Answer (score 1):

my friend!

There's an application called "Switcher Go". I've used it in the past to do what you say. I hope it works for you!

Comment: Cannot find it in the android playstore. In the apple appstore, theres an application called [Switcher Studio](https://www.apple.com/search/%22Switcher-Go%22?src=serp), does it have the multistream functionality ?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to that `Switcher Go` application ?